# Regex match everything except three consecutive double quotes

Tags: regex, jflex

I am trying to match everything except

```
"""
```

in Regex. My attempt includes:

```
[^\"]{3}
```

This only includes everything except a double quote. I want to also include one double quotes and two double quotes, so that, for instance, this entire string would match:

```
This example "" would match " all the way.
```

I am trying to make this work using JFlex.

Comment: Do you mean `^(?!.*""").*`? Any string not containing a "word"? What is the programming language / regex flavor? What is the final goal?

Comment: This works on regextester.com but results in an "Unterminated string at end of line." error in JFlex.

Comment: Sorry. I just realized you commented my answer saying you're using JFlex. I didn't know you were the one who asked the question, just realized it. Since no one answered, I'll try to help you from your tool.

Comment: It doesn't work on flex either, actually. I was double mistaken. Now I really would like to know the solution for this.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt @JudismarArpiniJunior! I was able to get a less-than-elegant solution involving three regex cases. Answer posted.

Comment: Great! I didn't get how to use those cases to build the final solution. Would you mind sharing your final regexp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to use several regex expressions:

```
[\"][\"][\"]   -> case (1) for three consecutive double quotes.
[^\"]+         -> case (2) for anything except a double quote
[\"]           -> case (3) grab one double quote
```

A string with two double quotes will then be "gobbled" one at a time. A string with three double quotes will choose case 1 because of the maximum munch rule and the precedence of case 1 over case 3.